ESP32-C3 framework location and how to change it
Our software package to date contains several projects for different STM32 MCUs. All projects and shared libraries are located under the same GIT repository root. There is a very convenient setting in the STM IDE called "copy necessary library files [into the project folder]". This way any branch/tag checkout guarantees the code can be compiled with whatever framework and library versions it was developed, regardless of IDE updates.
Now we have new ESP32-based module in the system. The software for it shares our own libraries and some other pieces from STM32 projects. So, naturally we want to place it under the same root to keep versions of all SW aligned.
The developer assigned to ESP32 project reports that most changes to default ESP-IDF locations result in compilation and/or linking breaking down. Even if something works the next toolchain update breaks it down again.
Is there an easy way to clone required framework packages and components into the project folder while keeping the rest of IDF tools at their default locations?
Or should we consider entire toolchain an indivisible required part and keep it in parallel GIT repository, branching and tagging it together with main code repository? This seems to be a very cumbersome solution.

Isn't this more a software engineering issue how to use the toolchain?

@Justme well, you are correct. There are plenty of MCU development questions here, but if you think it is out of place I'll delete it.

@Justme also, I've tried to search elsewhere else, but most of the hits are related to Arduino development. From Espressif forum I've got an impression that they want developers to follow well-defined path and not be too fancy about it.

Check  your project's CMakeLists.txt. It should include the path to the local components directory.
